# Use Redux-router with polymer 3 app

Tags: javascript, redux, polymer, polymer-3.x, redux-router

The polymer app is using redux to store app's state. The idea is to store all of the routing in state too (see the image below). 
I want to use redux-router for this, but I started to face problems already at the start when I try to import the library to my app.

[image]

The code of my import looks like this:

```
import { createStore, compose as origCompose, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { lazyReducerEnhancer } from 'pwa-helpers/lazy-reducer-enhancer';
import {ReduxRouter} from '../node_modules/redux-router/src/ReduxRouter.js'



import app from './reducers/app.js';
import route from './reducers/route.js';
import user from './reducers/user.js';
import events from './reducers/events.js';
```

The error I get with this import is:

> Unexpected token =

If I try to import like this:

```
import {ReduxRouter} from 'redux-router';
```

I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
>   '../../node_modules/redux-router/lib/index.js' does not provide an
>   export named 'ReduxRouter'

And if:

```
import {ReduxRouter} from '../node_modules/redux-router/src'
```

Then:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

The problem can be reproduced in starter polymer 3 app. Or, I think, in any polymer app.

So:

1. What is the right way to import?
2. Can I possibly use redux-router in
   a polymer app (without react) if I only need to store all the routes
   and history in state?
3. What other options do I have. Do you know any
   good libraries for that?

Answer (score 0):

1.)
Try:

```
    import 'redux-router';
```

If the npm package has a default export, this should allow you to reference it in the component. If not, try importing this on the end of index.html somewhere before  like:

```
    <script src="node_modules/redux-router/dist/ReduxRouter.js"></script>
    ...
    </body>
```

Note: */dist/* not */src/*

FYI, make sure you end your import statement with a semi-colon. You wrote:

```
    import { lazyReducerEnhancer } from 'pwa-helpers/lazy-reducer-enhancer';
    import {ReduxRouter} from '../node_modules/redux-router/src/ReduxRouter.js'
```

Your last line needs semi-colon (maybe a typo).

2.) Yes, it is possible.

3.) Check out the [pwa-starter-kit](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit) -- specifically look at how the Polymer group has included Redux and pwa-helpers/router.js for routing...